# R igraph crashes R session when loading graphml file created by python igraph

Tags: python, r, ubuntu, igraph

I'm in a bit strange situation that I have to create an igraph object in python and post process it in R. 
I found the rPython package on cran which allows me to execute python code in a R session.

In R, I use the following code to generate a python-igraph object and save it with the graphml format.

```
library(rPython)
library(igraph)

python.exec(c("from igraph import *",
              "g = Graph(directed = True)", 
              "g.add_vertices(3)",
              "g.add_edges([(0,1),(1,2)])",
              "fn = './test.graphml'",
              "g.write_graphml(fn)"))
```

Now if i try to load the file `test.graphml` in the very same R session with

```
g <- read.graph("./test.graphml", format = "graphml")
```

That session just crashes and returns the following error messages:

```
 *** caught segfault ***
address 0x59, cause 'memory not mapped'

Traceback:
1: .Call("R_igraph_read_graph_graphml", file, as.numeric(index),     PACKAGE = "igraph")
2: read.graph.graphml(file, ...)
3: read.graph("./test.graphml", format = "graphml")
aborting ...
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

If I start a new R session, I'm able to load the previous saved `test.graphml` with

```
g <- read.graph("./test.graphml", format = "graphml")
```

My python-igraph version is 0.7.0. and the R `sessionInfo()`

```
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C                LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=en_GB.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_GB.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_GB.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] igraph_0.7.0  rPython_0.0-5 RJSONIO_1.3-0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.1.2
```

**NOTE:** I only have this issue when runing ubuntu 14.04 where I couldn't find the latest version 0.7.1 for python-igraph. I've tested the same code in mac ox in which both my python (via mac port) and R igraph versions are 0.7.1. **It works just fine**. I'm wondering if this can be resolved by simply install version 0.7.1 for python-igraph.

Comment: I find your "Note" very strange. If you suspect this has been fixed in the current version, install the current version. If the error also occurs with that version, report it not here, but to the package maintainer/bug tracker.

Comment: The problem is that I couldn't find a version 0.7.1 Python igraph package. It is very much appreciated if anyone could give me a link. I'll test it out.

Comment: Hello; I'm the maintainer of the Python interface and there has not been an official 0.7.1 release for the Python interface so far due to lack of time. You can simply check out the latest source from the development branch on Github (https://github.com/igraph/python-igraph/tree/develop) and compile that. If it works, the issue has probably been fixed (although I have no idea what could have caused it as I don't remember doing anything specifically with the GraphML writer).

Comment: Hi Tamas, many thanks for your reply. I'm afraid the link doesn't work.

Comment: Can you show the `test.graphml` file?

Comment: @GaborCsardi, sure `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<graphml xmlns="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns
         http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns/1.0/graphml.xsd">
<!-- Created by igraph -->
  <graph id="G" edgedefault="directed">
    <node id="n0">
    </node>
    <node id="n1">
    </node>
    <node id="n2">
    </node>
    <edge source="n0" target="n1">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n1" target="n2">
    </edge>
  </graph>
</graphml>
`

Comment: This file works fine for me: `read.graph(rawConnection(charToRaw(xml)), format = "graphml")`

Comment: Oh, wait, need to try Ubuntu, too.

Comment: @GaborCsardi, many thanks for testing this out. My problem is not about reading the file. It's creating the graph file with python-igraph and reading the graph file via R-igraph in one R session.

Comment: @KeYuan Which means 1) writing it and the 2) reading it, no? Apparently writing is OK, and at least on OSX, reading is OK, too. Need to check reading on Linux.